# BigQuery Authentication Problems

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I'm starter with BigQuery. 
And my Problem comes with Authentication.
The credential File has been created and store at:

> /home/ltloi/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json

**Content:**

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxx",
  "private_key_id": "xxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "xxx",
  "client_id": "xxx",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/bigqueryservices1%40neon-deployment-141106.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

**Sourcecode:**

```
// just authentication with google big query
 public static Bigquery createAuthorizedClient() throws IOException {
    // Create the credential
    HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(transport, jsonFactory);

    // Depending on the environment that provides the default credentials (e.g. Compute Engine, App
    // Engine), the credentials may require us to specify the scopes we need explicitly.
    // Check for this case, and inject the Bigquery scope if required.
    if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
      credential = credential.createScoped(BigqueryScopes.all());
    }

    return new Bigquery.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("Bigquery Samples")
        .build();
  }
```

**The Problems Issue:**
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error reading credential file from location

> /home/ltloi/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json

**Error:**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
>           at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getCredentialUsingWellKnownFile(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:251)
>           at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredentialUnsynchronized(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:117)
>           at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:91)
>           at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:213)
>           at com.google.cloud.bigquery.samples.GettingStarted.createAuthorizedClient(GettingStarted.java:53)
>           at com.google.cloud.bigquery.samples.GettingStarted.main(GettingStarted.java:135)

When I try debug and the code shows that comes with SSL Issue form HttpClient.

Experts please help resolve it. I have try to add SSL of 
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs

But Can NOT resolve.

I also install Cloud SDK and But the also CAN NOT resolve.

```
{
  "client_id": "XXXX",
  "client_secret": "XXX",
  "refresh_token": "XXXX",
  "type": "authorized_user"
}
```

Note: I have Done **gcloud beta auth application-default login** **gcloud beta auth application-default print-access-token**

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Were the application default credentials created using the following command?

```
gcloud beta auth application-default login
```

I think there are two additional quick tests that you could do to get closer to the problem source. First, you can try this to verify that your credentials are fine:

```
gcloud beta auth application-default print-access-token
```

Then, you could copy and paste this brief python script to verify that it works (from here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/authentication)

```
# Grab the application's default credentials from the environment.
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
# Construct the service object for interacting with the BigQuery API.
bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
```

Comment: Hi, gcloud beta auth application-default login & gcloud beta auth application-default print-access-token work correctly.

Comment: The same Issue when I Try: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven